# Datastage XML Generation Issue

Tags: xml, datastage

For generation of new XML I had created an XSD first then created the job like below

Oracle connector>XML>XML_Output

In the edit assembly of XML stage>XML composer step I choose the option as
"Write to File " and provided output file directory and Filename prefix

the issue I am facing is for each input row DS is generating seperate XML output files.(eg:10 XML files for 10 input rows)
My requirement is to generate a single output XML file with all the input values.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two recommendations:

1. Check the Output -> Mappinng of the XML stage and assign the right level to the output link. Try assigning "top" to the name of the output link
2. Use  regular outputlink and do not let the XML Stage write directly to the file but use a separate Sequential File Stage

Comment: Thanks for the Response  When I assign TOP to XML stge the issue is I am not able to map any other below columns.Getting error like  CDIUI2826E When mapping a content Item (Non-List), the source node must be a content Item (Non-List).and CDIUI2820E The mapping is not applicable due to an invalid type conversion or difference in the source and target list dimensions...Please help!!

Comment: Ok - if is not mappable you have to adjust your XSD. Only level with minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" in the XSD are mappable. It is important to note that there are things (like that) that could only be fixed adjusting the XSD in combination with settings / mapping in the stage itself.

Comment: Could you please suggest what adjustments I need to do in XSD?

Comment: I did already -  if you need to map a certain element you have to define it in the XSD like that: <xs:element ref="Employee" minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded" /> (just a sample)

Comment: Thank you Michael!! I had did that and now only one file got generating but the issue now is only one record is populating no other records are showing up in the file!

Comment: @ MichaelTiefenbacher I Shall explain further 
Job1Oracle-4 rows-->XML_Stage-4 rows-->XMl Ouput Stage                                                 
Job2 Oracle-4 rows-->XML_Stage-1 row-->Sequential Stage             
In job 1 in the edit assembly of XML composer step I choose the option as "Write to File " and provided output file directory and Filename prefix 
If you see, 4 rows are reaching till xml output file stage but only one row is getting written in target!

Comment: In Job 2 in the edit assembly of XML stage>XML composer step I choose the option as pass as string and provided target sequential file with one column and the first row only getting passed from XML stage!I had followed the similar pattern from IBM sample composing job kit no idea what at all happening!! Please suggest!

Comment: I had created another job design as below

Oracle Connector -->Transformer-->XML output

I had followed exactly which is been said here:http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/ascential-l/using-the-xml-output-stage-in-datastage-80-3612038

Job is success with no warnings.But target file is not getting created.Could you suggest some possibilities? I am looking in the correct target path given in the option stage of XML output
File path:/fl***/F***/f***/tmp/test/n**/XML/N**_XML_OP.xml

Comment: I am confused - as far as I understand you hit your requirement to produce one file which was the original request - right? XML Output stage is a completly differnt thing - please you up to date stages and not the old ones. If you found my tips helpful please upvote them or mark my answer as solution.

Comment: Thank you MichaelTiefenbacher ,your solution helped me to generate a single file but with only single row instead of all input rows.For that I had created two jobs which was explained above.If you dont mind I would request your suggestions for resolving the issue

Comment: I see - I hope you understand that is hard to give exact recommendation with this amout of information and no hands on.... Another tip is while the number of result documents are defined in the Output step the XML is generated in the Composer. Try changing document root and/or your mapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions